# Swap div information from tabbed selection?

Tags: javascript, swap

I am attempting to make a tabbed "table" of sorts but I am having trouble making it display the information.

```js
  $(document).ready(function() {
    $('#orenk ul a').click(function() {
      $('#orenk ul a').removeClass('selected');
      $(this).addClass('selected');
      $('#orenk_changer').html(
        ('.' + $(this).attr('id') + '_content').html()
      );
    });
  });
```

```css
 body,
 html,
 div,
 ul,
 li,
 a {
   margin: 0;
   padding: 0;
 }
 body {
   font-family: arial;font-size:12px; color:#222;}
   .clear {
     clear: both;
   }
   a img {
     border: none;
   }
   ul {
     list-style: none;
     position: relative;
     z-index: 2;
     top: 1px;
     border-left: 1px solid #f5ab36;
   }
   ul li {
     float: left;
     width: 12.5%;
   }
   ul li a {
     background: #ffd89b;
     color: #222;
     display: block;
     padding: 6px 0px;
     text-decoration: none;
     border-right: 1px solid #f5ab36;
     border-top: 1px solid #f5ab36;
     border-right: 1px solid #f5ab36;
     text-align: center;
   }
   ul li a.selected {
     border-bottom: 1px solid #fff;
     color: #344385;
     background: #fff;
   }
   h1 {
     display: block;
     width: 600px;
     margin: 0 auto;
     padding: 20px 0;
     color: #fff;
   }
   #orenk {
     width: 900px;
     margin: 0 auto;
   }
   #tabs {
     width: 900px;
     margin: 0 auto;
   }
   #content {
     width: 900px;
     margin: 0 auto;
     height: 270px;
     background: #fff;
     z-index: 1;
     text-align: center;
     margin-bottom: 20px;
   }
```

```html
<div class="titlebg" style="padding: 4px; text-align: left; font-size: 20px;">
  ORENK PROVINCE
</div>
<div id="orenk">
  <ul>
    <li><a href="javascript:void(0);" id="province" class="selected province">ORENK PROVINCE</a>
    </li>
    <li><a href="javascript:void(0);" id="glass">Glass Shores</a>
    </li>
    <li><a href="javascript:void(0);" id="torrid">Torrid Terrain</a>
    </li>
    <li><a href="javascript:void(0);" id="plains">Muculent Plains</a>
    </li>
    <li><a href="javascript:void(0);" id="marsh">Ambrosial Marsh</a>
    </li>
    <li><a href="javascript:void(0);" id="expanse">Viscid Expanse</a>
    </li>
    <li><a href="javascript:void(0);" id="Opulent">Opulent Retreat</a>
    </li>
    <li><a href="javascript:void(0);" id="knolls">Reedy Knolls</a>
    </li>
  </ul>
  <div class="clear"></div>
</div>
<div id="content">
  <div id="orenk_changer">
    <img src="http://placehold.it/900x270">
  </div>
  <div id="glass_content" style="display: none;">Glass content test</div>
  <div id="torrid_content" style="display: none;">torrid content test</div>
  <div id="plains_content" style="display: none;">plains content test</div>
  <div id="marsh_content" style="display: none;">marsh content test</div>
  <div id="expanse_content" style="display: none;">expanse content test</div>
  <div id="Opulent_content" style="display: none;">opulent content test</div>
  <div id="knolls_content" style="display: none;">knolls content test</div>
</div>
```

I am VERY new to javascript and I can get it to display the id where I want the content but when I attempt to get it to show the html inside the container I am trying to call, it does nothing. It's incredibly frustrating. Any one care to point out what I am doing wrong and how to fix it?

Comment: [tag:java] != [tag:javascript]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

***[jsBin demo](http://jsbin.com/rodamu/1/)***

**Two things wrong** with your `('.' +`

- `$('.' +` ›missing `$`
- `$('#' +` ›you need to target `#` (Id) elements, not `.`(class)

```
  $('#orenk ul a').click(function( evt ) {
    evt.preventDefault();
    $('#orenk ul a').removeClass('selected');
    $(this).addClass('selected');
    $('#orenk_changer').html(
      $('#'+ this.id +'_content').html() // missing $ and # instead of .
    );
  });
```

---

Also, `a href="#"` (instead of `a href="javascript:void(0);"`) is quite enough if than inside JS you do [Event.preventDefault()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event/preventDefault)

Comment: Oh I completely missed changing the class back to id from when I was messing with it before that was a derp on my part. It works great now, thank you so much! I don't know why I didn't think of adding the $ before that section.